# How to set up Rolling MACD in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance, algorithmic-trading, rolling-computation

I can't figure out how to get a .rolling(30) MACD going on a set of data for the SPY ETF.

I want to do a rolling MACD on the last 30 days of data but I'm having a difficult time finding the right syntax.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime as dt

spy_df = data.get_data_yahoo("SPY", "2018-01-01", dt.date.today())[:-1]

def MACD(df, n_fast=12, n_slow=21):
    macd_df = pd.DataFrame()
    EMAfast = pd.Series(df.ewm(span=n_fast, min_periods=n_slow - 1).mean())
    EMAslow = pd.Series(df.ewm(span=n_slow, min_periods=n_slow - 1).mean())
    MACD = pd.Series(EMAfast - EMAslow, name='MACD')
    MACDsign = pd.Series(MACD.ewm(span=9, min_periods=8).mean(), name='MACDsignal')
    MACDdiff = pd.Series(MACD - MACDsign, name='MACDdiff')
    macd_df = macd_df.join(MACD)
    macd_df = macd_df.join(MACDsign)
    macd_df = macd_df.join(MACDdiff)
    return macd_df

macd_df = spy["Close"].rolling(30).apply(MACD, raw=False)
```

I keep getting type errors (`Must be real number not DataFrame` or `cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`").

I would generally like to use TA-Lib to accomplish this, but I don't know if that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Ta-Lib python wrapper. Please refer to

> https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/momentum_indicators.html

As simple as this:

```
macd, macdsignal, macdhist = MACD(close, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
```